# What does heroku domains:add really do behind the curtains?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns, cname

Lets say I have my app running on

**sakana.herokuapp.com**

and I own the domain **www.fishywebsites.com**

if I point my DNS **CNAME** for **fishywebsites** to point to **sakana.herokuapp.com** , shouldn't that be enough to render the website just fine?

What does doing

```
heroku domains:add www.fishywebsites.com
```

Actually do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku's [routing mesh](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing) accepts incoming HTTP requests and sends them to the appropriate application as it moves around the dyno grid. To do this, it relies on the HTTP `Host:` header, which corresponds to the domain name in the browser's address bar.

Heroku has a wildcard DNS entry that maps `*.herokuapp.com` to the routing mesh. You can connect to any name within this space, e.g. http://0gtxygq7t0haalc4.herokuapp.com/, even though there is no application with that name -- you connect to the routing mesh, which performs a lookup based on the `Host:` header, and determines that there's no sensible way to route this request.

Breaking that down: the browser sees the full URL, and pulls out the domain name. It then does a DNS lookup:

```
$ dig 0gtxygq7t0haalc4.herokuapp.com
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> 0gtxygq7t0haalc4.herokuapp.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 38567
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;0gtxygq7t0haalc4.herokuapp.com.    IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
0gtxygq7t0haalc4.herokuapp.com. 60 IN   A   23.21.103.189

;; Query time: 128 msec
;; SERVER: 2001:470:20::2#53(2001:470:20::2)
;; WHEN: Wed Dec  5 17:04:36 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 64
```

This tells the browser to connect to 23.21.103.189. Pairing that with the protocol (`http`), it establishes a TCP connection to that IP on port 80. The routing mesh doesn't know or care how you found it, since the DNS lookup involved a totally separate set of servers -- all it knows is that you're connecting to it.

The browser then sends something like:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 0gtxygq7t0haalc4.herokuapp.com
...
```

This is when the Heroku routing mesh find out which site you want.

If you add a CNAME entry for `foo.bar.baz` to `*.herokuapp.com`, you'll succeed in connecting that name to the routing mesh. However, until you `heroku domains:add foo.bar.baz`, Heroku doesn't know which application should receive those requests -- it'll see `Host: foo.bar.baz`, and it has no idea which application is involved. The DNS lookup operates at a layer underneath HTTP, and you need both in order to route your application.

Answer (score 0):

```
heroku domains:add www.fishywebsites.com
```

Tells to heroku that every request that goes to www.fishywebsites.com should be routed to your application (in this case to the sakana application).

So unfortunately, pointing www.fishywebsites.com to heroku won't be enough. Have in mind that an application can have any name, and that a domain doesn't need to math the name of the app, and that probably is quicker for heroku to update their dns and routing system based on the user setup rather than guess where to redirect each request.

Anyway, adding a domain to heroku shouldn't take more than 1 minute, not a big deal.